# Dropbox 1.6.0 connexion menu greyed out with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, 13.10, dropbox

I installed DropBox over my new installation of Ubuntu 13.10 (Unity desktop) with the installation .deb file from [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=linux) (64-bit). (I installed also its dependency python-gpgme.)

It worked before (less than two weeks) in my Ubuntu 13.10 (Gnome desktop, not this one) and then in an ArchLinux with Gnome desktop (less than one week) but now the application is installed and I have the connexion menu greyed out as you can see:

[image: Connexion's menu greyed]
(The menu is in french.)

You can see this video on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EM7CJAl8v4

Any clues?

Comment: No clue. Have you tried to delete .dropbox and .dropbox-dist folders?. This will erase all your config (.dropbox) and force it to download again the proprietary daemon (dropbox-dist).

Comment: Yep. I tried but still greyed. Tried even to download the "daemon" package alone (after `remove --purge` and `rm -r ~/dropbox-dist`).